# Combine hash keys and values if keys are identical except for case

Tags: ruby

Let's say I have a Ruby Hash where at least two keys are identical, except for their case, for instance:

```
{ 'Foo' => 1, 'foo' => 2, 'bar' => 3 }
```

Is there a way I can combine like keys (except for their case) such that the resulting Hash might look like this?

```
{ 'foo' => 3, 'bar' => 3 }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a new hash:

```
new_hash = Hash.new(0)
old_hash.each_pair { |k, v| new_hash[k.downcase] += v }
```

Comment: `Hash.new` really simplifies things - setting the default value of new keys to 0 is really helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `inject` to loop all the hash items and build a new hash.

```
hash = { 'Foo' => 1, 'foo' => 2, 'bar' => 3 }
hash.inject({}) do |result, (key, value)|
  key = key.downcase
  result[key] = result[key] ? result[key] + value : value
  result
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more way of doing this

```
h = { 'Foo' => 1, 'foo' => 2, 'bar' => 3 }
p h.collect{|k, v| {k.downcase => v}}.reduce { |a, v| a.update(v) {|k, o, n| o + n } }
#=> {"foo"=>3, "bar"=>3}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
h = { 'Foo' => 1, 'foo' => 2, 'bar' => 3 }

h.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),g| g[k.downcase] = g[k.downcase].to_i + v }
  #=> {"foo"=>3, "bar"=>3}
```

This makes use of the fact that if `g` does not have a key `e`, `g[e]` on the right side will equal `nil` and `nil.to_i #=> 0`. On the other hand, if `g` has a key `e`, `h[e].to_i` will equal `h[e]`.

Another way:

```
h.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),g| g.update(k.downcase=>v) { |_,o,v| o+v } }
  #=> {"foo"=>3, "bar"=>3}
```